# DIY ultrasonic sensor

Tags: ltspice, ultrasound

I attached the link for the project I am trying to implement. Instead of using an Arduino, I will use either an ESP32 or an STM34.

What is the purpose of the MAX232? Is there something else I can use instead of this? Also, I need to run a simulation on LTspice and am not sure how to represent the LM324 or the MAX232. I do not understand much of this because I am still a student with limited experience. I would appreciate any help.

Here is the link to the project:
http://electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut36.php

[image]

Comment: MAX232 creates high voltage to drive transmitter.

Answer (score 2):

The [MAX232](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX220-MAX249.pdf) generates +/- high voltage rails (something like +/-9V) and acts as a driver (H-bridge) so the transducer sees something like 36Vp-p from a 5V rail when driven in push-pull.

[image]

The high voltage rails are generated by an on-chip oscillator driving charge pumps (which is why we need all those capacitors).